# How to merge complex data frames in pandas/dataframe-js/etc

Tags: pandas, danfojs, dataframe-js

I would imagine what I'm trying to do is fairly simple in pandas but I just can't get it.
Really I want to do this in `dataframe-js` (or `danfojs`) but any help in either `pandas` or `dataframe-js` will be helpful.

Essentially:

- there can be an array of any number of dataframes with any number of rows and columns.
- They should all have at least one matching column `uuid`.
- Most of the dataframes will have data for every `uuid` but some might be missing.
- The only known column name is `uuid`, so using "merge on" or similar with any other column name isn't an option.

example dataframes:

```
    let data1 = [
      [['col A', 'uuid'], ['1238', '12']],
      [['col B', 'uuid'], ['42.4', '12']],
      [['col A', 'uuid'], ['1091', '48']],
      [['col B', 'uuid'], ['35.1', '48']],
      [['col B', 'uuid'], ['44.4', '77']],
    ]
```

desired output (column order doesn't matter):

```
[
      ['col A', 'uuid', 'col B'],
      ['1238', '12', '42.4'],
      ['1091', '48', '35.1'],
      [null, '77', '44.4'] // null, undefined, NaN...doesn't matter for the gaps
]
```

please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I combined @onyambu's answer with the `merge` function, which now accepts dataframes of different sizes

```
# create an initial empty df
t = pd.DataFrame(columns=['uuid'])

# reduce list of dataframes into one
df = reduce(lambda x,y: x.merge(pd.DataFrame(y[1:], columns=y[0]), how='outer'), data1, t)

# squash rows on `uuid` index with stack/unstack
df = df.set_index('uuid').stack().unstack().reset_index()

# output in original "table" format
df2 = np.r_[df.columns.values[None],df.iloc[:].values].tolist()
print(df2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(map(lambda x: dict(zip(*x)), data1)).set_index('uuid').
      stack().unstack().reset_index())

df2 = np.r_[df.columns.values[None,[1,0,2]],df.iloc[:,[1,0,2]].values].tolist()
print(df2)

[['col A', 'uuid', 'col B'],
 ['1238', '12', '42.4'],
 ['1091', '48', '35.1'],
 [nan, '77', '44.4']]
```

Comment: wow, mind blown. -- `stack().unstack()` ...is that really the best way to "squash" all the NaNs after the zip? I'm just thinking to translate this to `dataframe-js` they don't have stack/unstack

Comment: dang, looks like this fails when the number of values in a data frame is more than 2, for example: ```  [
    [['col A', 'uuid'], ['1238', '12'], ['1091', '48']],
    [['col B', 'uuid'], ['42.4', '12']],
    // [['col A', 'uuid'], ['1091', '48']],
    [['col B', 'uuid'], ['35.1', '48']],
    [['col B', 'uuid'], [null, '77']],
    [['col A', 'uuid'], [undefined, '77']],
    [['col C', 'uuid'], ['21453', '77']],
  ]```

Comment: @André it will fail because it does not take that into account. Also that seems to be an ill-defined format. Note that you have for each pair of values you previously had the column headers. For example you have B, uid, Num1, Num2 then B uid, Num3, Num4..  You do not have B, uid, Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4.. So why would A have that format? That is an afterthought format. ie Every solution in coding will faill if given the data in not a previously intended method. even `sum` will fail is the data is not correct.